# Is there a reason why Spring MVC doesn't apply a limit to the maximum number of bytes to buffer in memory for input stream like WebFlux?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, deserialization, spring-webflux

For the first time I noticed this error in my Spring WebFlux application:

> org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferLimitException: Exceeded
> limit on max bytes to buffer : 262144

So WebFlux has a limit that it checks while deserializing client payload as described in the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-codecs-limits). I am curious to know why this check is not done in Spring Web MVC. Is an innovation for the most recent WebFlux or is there a technical reason for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the features of WebFlux is its ability to process incoming requests as a stream. This means that the input request's stream could potentially be endless, leading to a possible "out of memory" problem. That's why WebFlux's `Decorer`s and `HttpMessageReader`s offer a useful feature with their `maxInMemorySize` properties. They can calculate the size of incoming chunks and trigger a `DataBufferLimitException` if the accumulated size exceeds the specified limit.

As for Spring MVC, the difference is that MVC usually relies on Servlet containers (like Tomcat, etc.) to process it. Whereas WebFlux relies on Netty and processes that part by themselves. So in MVC, you can limit input request size on the servlet container level, but in WebFlux, you need this property.

The reason for its implementation can be traced back to the original issue, which can be found at:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23884

The code is available here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/871464811cc1b18d684408f71725cead20c70796

Comment: I imagine that mvc will receive a stream of bytes as well. Every data that goes trough a network is streamed. When reading bytes from a channel web mvc could check the amount of bytes it is buffering

Comment: You are correct that data transmitted over a network (TCP) is streamed. The difference is that MVC usually relies on Servlet containers (like Tomcat, etc.) to process it. Whereas WebFlux relies on Netty and processes that part by themselves. So in MVC, you can limit input request size on the servlet container level, but in WebFlux, you need this property.

Comment: Ok, I imaged this answer. If you complete your initial response with what you said above I can vote it. Thank you.

Comment: @SGiux, Thank you, I have updated my response. I am glad to assist you.